# How to correctly display the SUM of values in room database?

Tags: database, kotlin, date, sum, calendar

I want to display the sum of calories consumed on a selected day via CalendarView, if it is possible. The value of calories are stored in a database using Room Database, which gets its values from HomeFragment, and I would like to display the sum in CalendarFragment.

The problem is, the app crashes without any LogCat info when I click on the fragment

**FoodData.kt**

```
@Parcelize
@Entity(tableName = "food_table")
data class FoodData(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    val id: Int,
    val name: String,
    val calories: Int,
    val date: String,
): Parcelable
```

**inside FoodDao.kt**

```
@Query("SELECT SUM(calories) as calories FROM food_table WHERE date BETWEEN startday AND endday")
fun sumCalories(startday: Date, endday: Date): Int
```

**FoodRepository.kt**

```
fun sumCalories(startday: java.util.Date, endday: java.util.Date): Int{
    return foodDao.sumCalories(startday, endday)
}
```

**FoodViewModel.kt**

```
fun sumCalories(startday: java.util.Date, endday: java.util.Date):Int{
        return repository.sumCalories(startday, endday)
    }
```

**CalendarFragment.kt**

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        mFoodViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(FoodViewModel::class.java)
        setupCalendar()

        val formatter = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
        val sDate = binding.calendarView.date.toString()
        val sDateplus = (binding.calendarView.date + 86400000).toString() //I used this to add 1 day

        binding.tvSumCal.text = mFoodViewModel.sumCalories(formatter.parse(sDate)!!, formatter.parse(sDateplus)!!).toString()
    }
```